# Rails : has_many_and_belongs_to on 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models in my Ruby on Rails say publisher, author and book. I want to create many to many relationship among them.

I have created a table called authors_books_publishers and added has_many_and_belongs_to in them.. for e.g.

```
Author
has_many_and_belongs_to :books
has_many_and_belongs_to :publishers

Book
has_many_and_belongs_to :authors
has_many_and_belongs_to : publishers

Publisher
has_many_and_belongs_to :authors
has_many_and_belongs_to :books
```

But it doesn't work when I try to add books in author

```
a = Author.new
b = Book.new 
a.books << b
```

It says (and rightly so) that system doesn't find a table called authors_books.

Please help

P.S. please treat the above models as e.g. They are not the real names in my app.

Thanks,

Comment: I just answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375131/custom-db-entry-for-3-way-habtm-in-ror/8418075#8418075

Comment: Maybe you meant 'has_and_belongs_to_many'. I don't know this kind of 'has_many_and_belongs_to' association.

Comment: According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many if you use has_and_belongs_to_many you need to make sure to create a join table, so in your case authors_books table

Answer (score 1):

you have to create 3 separate tables:

1. `authors_books`
2. `books_publishers`
3. `authors_publishers`

and you probably the `authors_publishers` association is redundant b/c you could do same thing with `author has_many :publishers, :thorough => :books`

Answer (score 0):

I did an article on active record associations a little while ago, here's the link;

http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/basic-activerecord-associations-overview/

I think it may involve the :through symbol. I am by no means a rails expert (trying to become one!) but hopefully that'll help.