# Modeling schools database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here what i need:

- School has many teachers
- Teachers can belong to one or more schools
- Subject can belong to one or more teachers
- Teachers can has many subjects

How can i make a relationship that store:

Teacher A works in School 1 and School 2, but he teach math and physics in he School 1 and only math in the School 2?

Here what im already done:

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :school_teachers
    has_many :teachers, through: :school_teachers
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :school_teachers
    has_many :schools, through: :school_teachers
end

class SchoolTeacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :teacher
end


class Subject < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: school_teachers exists because will store Teacher A with School 1 and Teacher A with School 2...

Comment: OK, so this is really a "has and belongs to many" relationship where you plan to do things with the `school_teachers` model?

Comment: What you suggest?

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps a `SchoolTeacher` `has_many` subjects. And `Subject` `belongs_to` `school_teacher`. A "subject" is associated with a teacher-school pairing, so this makes sense.

Comment: school_teacher only makes sense if a teacher teachers at different schools and a school having many trachers

Comment: Actually, maybe it should be a `SchoolTeacher` `belongs_to :subject`. And then `Subject` `has_many :school_teachers`, etc... And then you can ponder whether it should really be called `SchoolTeacherSubject`. :)

Comment: But a teacher can teach in different schools. @rajbir

Comment: ofcourse that works @Eduardorph, your business cases drives your logic

Answer (score 3):

Since a subject is associated with one or more school & teacher pairings, then I would suggest this may really be a 3-way "has and belongs to many" relationship.

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :school_teacher_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :school_teacher_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :school_teacher_subjects
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :school_teacher_subjects
  has_many :schools, through: :school_teacher_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :school_teacher_subjects
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :school_teacher_subjects
  has_many :schools, through: :school_teacher_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :school_teacher_subjects
end

class SchoolTeacherSubject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

Here's an example of a 3-way HABTM relationship for customers, phones, and addresses: [Custom db entry for 3 way habtm in ROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375131/custom-db-entry-for-3-way-habtm-in-ror#answer-8418075)
.

Comment: This is a good model.  It might also be the case that the designer might create a "SchoolsTeacher" model, and then tie Subject to a particular SchoolsTeacher.  The reason is that there might be some redundancy inherent in the above model since teachers are probably more tightly bound to particular schools, but might teach a number of subjects within that school.

Comment: @MichaelChaney yes, indeed, great comment.

Comment: Exactly what i want @MichaelChaney

Comment: @Eduardorph I was originally thinking along those lines. Then I realized that a single subject might apply to potentially many school-teacher pairings. That landed me on the 3-way HABTM.